# Use subprocess module to open an executable, and send data to it

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to open an executable file using the `subprocess` module, then wait for the program to open and finally to input into it a username and a password. The program's username input page looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

And here is the code:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from time import sleep

command = bytes("test\n", encoding='utf8')
p = Popen("name.exe", stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)
sleep(12)
print("Sending...")
p.stdin.write(command)
sleep(1)
p.stdin.write(command)
print("Sent!")
print("Resp: \n" + str(p.stdout.read()))
print("Err: \n" + str(p.stderr.read()))
print("Finished!")
```

What is weird is that I never see the command actually be written on the screen, any knowledge on where this could come from?

Comment: Don't forget to call `p.stdin.flush()` after write.

Comment: This program is a GUI application. STDIN and STDOUT are used by console applications. Do you want to enter login data its GUI, into the login field?

Comment: Yes if possible

Comment: This is called "GUI automation". There are many GUI automation tools for Windows. If you prefer using Python code, you can use **pywinauto** to automate GUI applications: https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto There are many pywinauto tutorials on the web.

Comment: If you programmatically enter the password into the subprocess, you will have created a security hazard.

Comment: Thx @kol, this is exactly what I was looking for. I didn't know that there was an actual difference between GUI and CL apps.